# NPAPI plugin get NPP_Destroy right NPAPI_New in Safari 7.0.2

Tags: macos, plugins, osx-mavericks, npapi, safari7

We have a NPAPI internet plug-in, that is loaded from a certain web page (https). With the new Safari 7.0.2 it receives `NPAPI_Destroy` right after `NPAPI_New` call, failing the call of one of the exposed functions.

We do support core graphics drawing model and  cocoa event handling model.

Our plugin doesn’t actually draw and doesn’t have a window. All that it does - to load an external application with the parameters, that are passed from the plugin.

In the html page it’s loaded as embed = from the java script.

We build it with universal 32/64 bit architecture. This problem started with the new version of Safari 7.0.2  on Mavericks 10.9.2.

Additional reload of the pages solves the problem and the plugin does its work.

Thanks in advance for any clues

Thanks in advance,
Nava

Comment: anything in the system console?

Comment: nope, just NPAPI_Destroy after NPAPI_New

Comment: This isn't much of an answer, but I'd try building an example from FireBreath (FBTestPlugin); see if that works or not.  If it does, you can compare what is going on between the two plugins and maybe track it down.  If it doesn't, at least you're in good company?